# Searching and deleting values in a circular linked list

Tags: java

I am trying to make an application that will loop through a **circular linked list**. As it does so, it will use another `linked list` of index values, and it will use these values to delete from the **circular linked list**.

I have it set up now where it should fetch the index value to be deleted from my random `linked list` via `runRandomList()` method. It then uses the `rotate()` method to loop through the **circular linked list** and deletes the value from it. It will then add the deleted value to "deletedLinked list". Then, control should return back to `runRandomList()` method and it should feed the `rotate()` method the next value from the random linked list. The **circular linked list** should begin traversing where it left off. It should keep track of the count and node it is on. The count should reset to 0 when it reaches the first node, so it can properly keep track of which index it is on.

Unfortunately, this is not happening. I have been trying different things for the last few days as the code stands right now; it enters into a continuous loop. the issue appears to be in the `rotate method`.

This is the `rotate method` code. My thought was the counter would advance until it matches the index input. If it reaches the first node, the counter would reset to 0 and then start to increment again until it reaches the index value.

```
private void rotate(int x)       
{ 

while(counter <= x)
{
 if(p == names.first)
 {
 counter = 0;
 }
 p = p.next;
 counter++;
}

deleteList.add((String) p.value);
names.remove(x);

}
```

This is my linked list class:

```
public class List<T>{


/*
helper class, creates nodes
*/
public class Node {

T value;
Node next;

/*
Inner class constructors
*/

public Node(T value, Node next)
{
   this.value = value;
   this.next = next;

}

 private Node(T value)
{
   this.value = value;

}
}

 /*
Outer class constructor
*/

Node first;
Node last;

public int size()
{
    return size(first);
}

 private int size(Node list)
 {
    if(list == null)
        return 0;

    else if(list == last)
        return 1;

    else
    {
     int size = size(list.next) + 1;

     return size;
    }
 }


public void add(T value)
{
first = add(value, first);   
}


private Node add(T value, Node list)
{  
    if(list == null)
    {  
        last = new Node(value);
        return last;
    }

    else
        list.next = add(value, list.next);

        return list;
}

public void setCircularList()
{
    last.next = first;

}

public void show()
{
    Node e = first;
    while (e != null)
    {
    System.out.println(e.value);
    e = e.next;
    }
}

 @Override
public String toString()
{
  StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

  // Use p to walk down the linked list
  Node p = first;
  while (p != null)
  {
     strBuilder.append(p.value + "\n"); 
     p = p.next;
  }      
  return strBuilder.toString(); 
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    boolean result = isEmpty(first);
    return result;
}

private boolean isEmpty(Node first)
{
   return first == null;
}


public class RemovalResult
{
   Node node;     // The node removed from the list
   Node list;     // The list remaining after the removal
   RemovalResult(Node remNode, Node remList)
   {
     node = remNode;
     list = remList;
   }
}     

/**
   The remove method removes the element at an index.
   @param index The index of the element to remove. 
   @return The element removed.  
     @exception IndexOutOfBoundsException When index is 
              out of bounds.     
*/

public T remove(int index)
{    
   // Pass the job on to the recursive version
   RemovalResult  remRes = remove(index, first);     
   T element = remRes.node.value;  // Element to return
   first = remRes.list;                 // Remaining list
   return element;      
}  

/**
   The private remove method recursively removes 
   the node at the given index from a list.
   @param index The position of the node to remove.
   @param list The list from which to remove a node.
   @return The result of removing the node from the list.
   @exception IndexOutOfBoundsException When index is 
              out of bounds.  
  */
   private RemovalResult remove(int index, Node list)
   {
   if (index < 0 || index >= size())
   {  
       String message = String.valueOf(index);
       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(message);
   }

   if (index == 0)
   {
       // Remove the first node on list
       RemovalResult remRes;
       remRes = new RemovalResult(list, list.next);
       list.next = null;
       return remRes;           
   }  

   // Recursively remove the element at index-1 in the tail
   RemovalResult remRes;
   remRes = remove(index-1, list.next);

   // Replace the tail with the results and return
   // after modifying the list part of RemovalResult
   list.next = remRes.list;    
   remRes.list = list;
   return remRes;
}


}
```

This contains the `main()`, `runRandomList()`, and `rotate()` methods.

```
public class lottery {

private int suitors;
private List<String> names;
private List<Integer> random;
private List<String> deleteList = new List<>();
private int counter;
private Node p;




public lottery(int suitors, List<String> names, List<Integer> random)
{   
 this.suitors = suitors;
 this.names = names;
 this.random = random;
 p = names.first;
 }


 public void start()
 {  
 //Set names list to circular
  names.setCircularList();
  runRandomList(random);
}

public void runRandomList(List<Integer> random)
{
Node i = random.first;
while(i != null)
{
    rotate((int) i.value, counter, p);
    i = i.next; 
}

}

public List getDeleteList()
{
return deleteList;
}      

private void rotate(int x, int count, Node p)       
{ 
Node i = p; 
while(count <= x)
{
 if(i == names.first)
 {
    count = 0;
 }
    i = i.next;
    count++;
}

deleteList.add((String) i.value);
names.remove(x);
p = i;
counter = count;
}



public static void main(String[] args)
{
List<String> namesList = new List<>();
namesList.add("a");
namesList.add("b");
namesList.add("c");
namesList.add("d");
namesList.add("e");
namesList.add("f");

List<Integer> randomList = new List<>();
randomList.add(3);
randomList.add(1);
randomList.add(5);
randomList.add(4);
randomList.add(0);



lottery obj = new lottery(6, namesList, randomList);

obj.start();
System.out.println(obj.getDeleteList());




}
}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to debug ;)

Comment: You dump your entire code and expect someone to go through all of it and find where it deviates from your convoluted description? Unlikely to happen. Use divide and conquer: Test each part separately and ensure it does what you expect it to do. This will find you the problem, and if you still can't solve it, come back here and ask a narrowly constrainted question.

Comment: That's what I tried to do actually. I went piece by piece. The issue happens in the rotate method, but I cant figure out why.

Comment: The circular linked list works, the add and remove methods works, but I am having issues with the rotate method.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected it was the rotate method, this is the solution.

```
private void rotate(int x, int count)       
{ 
 while(count != x)
{
 p = p.next;
 count++;

 if(count == x)
 {
   deleteList.add((String)p.value);  
   counter = x;
 }
 if(count >= suitors)
 { 
     for (int j = 0; j < x ; j++)
     {
          p = p.next;
     }
        deleteList.add((String)p.value);
        counter = x; 
        count = x;   
 }                 
 }

 }
```